# Remove elements from list with recursion c++

Tags: c++

I have this function that should delete elements that are multiple of input number.

```
ptr_lista rmv_mul(ptr_list p,int n){

    if(p==NULL){
      return(p);
    }

    if (p->val%n==0){
        ptr_list tmp;             
        tmp = p->next;
        delete(p);
        rmv_mul(p->next,n);
        return (p);
    }
    else{
        rmv_mul(p->next,n);
        return (p);
    }
}
```

Executing this on a list from 0 to 10, the problem is that elements are deleted but are not null, so my print function gives me this:

```
0 28992848 28992816 28992784 28992752 28992720 28992688 28992656 28992624 28992592
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Not working, i get segmentation fault.

Comment: You should be first attempting to delete 3 nodes, and when you get that working, then see if it works for 10 nodes.  This way, it becomes easier to work with.

Comment: It would be so extremely easy with `std::list`'s `remove_if` member function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code ignores the return value of `rmv_mul`, even though that's the new list pointer. Instead of returning `p` in the first branch, your code should be returning whatever is returned by `rmv_mul`:

```
ptr_lista rmv_mul(ptr_list p,int n){
    if(p==NULL){
      return(p);
    }
    if (p->val%n==0){
        ptr_list tmp = p->next;
        delete(p);
        return rmv_mul(tmp, n); // <<== Pass tmp, not p; p is deleted
    } else {
        p->next = rmv_mul(p->next, n); // <<== Assign to p->next
        return (p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working, now i get `15353168 15353136 15353104 15353072 15353040 15353008 15352976 15352944 15352912`, so it deletes first element too if i set n=1

Comment: @slash89mf Are you calling it properly, i.e `mylist = rmv_mul(mylist, 4)`?

Comment: Yes, in my main i have this: `q=rmv_mul(q,x);`

Comment: @slash89mf It works perfectly for me ([demo](http://ideone.com/Jy5Nq2)).

Answer (score 1):

Without even trying to follow your logic these two lines already show you've a problem:

```
delete(p);
rmv_mul(p->next,n);
```

the reason is that after `delete p` (no parenthesis needed, btw) you are not allowed to access `p->next` (it's undefined behavior).